# Editing a file does not seem to refresh Django pycache

Tags: django

I am currently trying to create my own user auth model in Django by removing the username field and replacing it with only an email field.

The model is stored in it's own file in `app.user`.

I keep getting this error:

> app.User: (auth.E003) 'User.email' must be unique because it is named as the 'USERNAME_FIELD'.

Now, I changed the line to the email field to be:

```
email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
```

but for some reason I cannot seem to get it to bite, or any edit in that file. In fact I can delete the file and `runserver`, even on full restart, will say the same error.

As soon as I make an edit to settings.py or something it bites and works, without refreshing the cache for the user model though (only updating the cache for those it detects edited).

This has led me to believe that edits to this file are not correctly updating it's pycache.

How can I get this file to be scanned and updated by Django?

Comment: Did you create a migration and migrate? Changing a model field doesn't automatically change the underlying database.

Comment: @MadWombat ah is that telling me about the DB?

Comment: @MadWombat no, you see when I run pyhon3 manage.py makemigrations app is comes out with that error, I cannot even make the migrations

Comment: Hold on... you are saying that your user model is not stored in models.py. That might be a problem. Did you use AUTH_USER_MODEL to substitute your model for the default?

Comment: @MadWombat indeed, I got it pointing to my model like so: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'`

Comment: If you are not storing the User model in models.py I am pretty sure it will not find it. The syntax for AUTH_USER_MODEL is 'app_name.model_name' and it expects the model to be located in models.py file.

Comment: @MadWombat that was it, I had this model in models.py as well and when I edited that it worked. It is weird because I followed the django doc to put it in it's own file. It is now talking about migrations which is the right path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your custom User model into app.models and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL='app.User'`. Django parses AUTH_USER_MODEL value as 'app_name.model_name' and then attempts to do `from app_name.models import model_name`, so if the model is not in models.py it will not be found.

Here is the doc link for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model